# Does my MySQL schema make sense? Any recommendations?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to create a database that stores the following content (about 5,765 entries total): http://s18.postimg.org/s73exwemf/Capture.jpg

I'm using MySQL Workbench to create my schema. So far I have one table with the following columns:

**EPSG Code** (INT) - PK, NN

**CRS_NAME** CHAR(50) - UQ

**CRS_TYPE** - ENUM('Projected', 'Geographic 2D', 'Geographic 3D', 'Geocentric', 'Vertical', 'Compound')

**PROJ_FILE** - CHAR(800)

---

Do my dataypes make sense? Generally, I will retrieve the CRS Name, type and proj file contents using the EPSG code. But sometimes, the only information available may be the CRS name. That's why I made CRS_NAME a unique index.

Does that make sense? I'm new to SQL and I'm enjoying it so far.

Answer (score 1):

The following is for the most part personal preferences developed over almost 10 years of working with databases (MySQL mostly).

- **CRS_NAME:** Unique key sounds appropriate to me.
- **CRS_TYPE:** I tend to stay away from enum in the database. Instead, I suggest a separate CRS_TYPE table, and putting a CRS_TYPE_ID field
  in the table instead of an enum type. I would not make CRS_TYPE.ID an
  auto-increment; ideally, you want it to reflect the values used in an
  enum in whatever programming language you might work with.
  (Technically, the additional table is only necessary for
  documentation and easier reporting purposes.)
- **PROJ_FILE:** `TINYTEXT`, `MEDIUMTEXT`, `TEXT`, etc... might be a better option (or equivalent `BLOB`s). `CHAR(800)` is going to use 800 (or more
  depending on character set) bytes whether it holds nothing or is
  full. `VARCHAR(800)` could be better (from a space used perspective), but if
  using MyISAM engine, causes data rows to be dynamic (slowing
  queries). Regardless of engine used, TEXT and BLOB types only take up
  as much room as they need and don't "fragment" tables like VARCHAR.
  The  downside is they are little more complicated to search within
  and index.

Comment: Thanks! This is pretty helpful! So would it look something like this? http://s15.postimg.org/sab4r2d6h/Capture.jpg  Now I'm trying to understand how the appropiate CRS type will be assigned to whatever EPSG I look up.

Comment: CRS_TYPE should only need an id field and a single `type_name` varchar(32) field. Starting out, it would only have 6 rows (type_name fields = "Projected", "Geographic", etc...), and would only need a new row in circumstances that would have required you to alter the original enum definition. Also, you don't need to specify a length on a `TEXT` field.

Comment: Sweet! I apologize for all the noob questions. Thank you for sharing the knowledge!

Comment: Try not use text for filename because it's expensive. For newcomers, try use varchar instead of char, except for very short values. Also try not to use enum. It sounds good but may give you headaches, as uueerdo explained.

Comment: Yes, if PROJ_FILE is a filename, use CHAR or VARCHAR. My TEXT/BLOB suggestion was assuming you were storing the contents of small files.

Comment: I disagree with the comments above about ENUM.  Adding a lookup table for those codes will give you extra complexity for very few advantages.  If you do need a lookup table for those codes, which is unlikely, you can still join using the enum and pick up any extra description info or whatever.  Keep it simple!

Comment: It doesn't really add any complexity as long as you handle it how I suggested. Chances are most queries are going to be perform in code. Any decent language supports integer valued enums. With a MySQL ENUM-typed field, if you wanted to rename a "type", you'd have to find and update every relevant string value in every code base referencing the enum... AND do a very expensive ALTER TABLE. Using the alternative I suggested, no table alterations are needed, joins are reliably fast, and renaming the "type" involves an optional refactor of the enum in code and one row update in the "type" table.